# Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, command, c++

## Question

1. Why I'm got this error ?`Resource temporarily unavailable`
2. How to launch over 10,000 threads with no error?
   I want to run my code with over 10,000 threads.

## Steps to reproduce this issue

1. Write code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread ()
{
  sleep(9999);
}

int main()
{
  int err = 0, count = 0;
  pthread_t tid;

  while (err == 0)
  {
    err = pthread_create (&tid, NULL, thread, NULL);
    count++;
  }
  printf("max thread: %d\n", count);
  getchar();
}
```

2. Compile & Run

```
$ gcc source.c -pthread
$ ./a.out &
max thread: 10800
```

3. run commands

```
$ touch abc
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

$ vim abc
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

root@~# cd /etc
-bash: wait_for: No record of process 21875
root@/etc#
```

## What i tried

1. change kernel parameters, but not fixed

```
sysctl -w kernel.threads-max=600000
sysctl -w kernel.pid_max=600000
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=600000
reboot
```

2. change `pids.max`, but not fixed.

```
$ vim /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-0.slice/pids.max
999999
$ reboot
```

## Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04
- CPU 32 Core
- Memory 64 GB

```
$ ulimit - a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257435
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257435
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
514870
```

Comment: I had same problem working in heavily multithreaded code in Python. 
I solved working explictly on setrlimit (RLIMIT_NOFILE) in my code, the same should apply to C as well.

Comment: I'm already change `nofile` limit to 65536, but not fixed yet. https://i.imgur.com/XlE7YAE.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344203/maximum-number-of-threads-per-process-in-linux